# where are sources for ubuntu sdk qtmultimedia?

Tags: 13.10, phone, ubuntu-sdk, source-code

As someone who intends to blend c++ with qml, I need to wrap my head around some examples.  The phablet-team has a camera app that does a good job of demonstrating that.
I noticed that Camera is a type the camera app imports from qtmultimedia if I understand correctly.  So digging under the hood some more I want to look at the qtmultimedia sources that ubuntu-phone uses.

Hopefully the ubuntu phone's camera app source is this one, but I am not certain:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/camera-app/trunk/files
Is that correct?

Where are the specific qtmultimedia sources which this camera app imports?

Answer (score 1):

Digging deep into synaptic, I was able to find the ubuntu-sdk dependencies and libs and found
qtmultimedia5-dev.  The sources are not installed.  Only the developer headers and compiled libs are installed by default.  That's why I was having difficulty finding them.

Get the sources:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qtmultimedia5-dev
sudo apt-get source --compile qtmultimedia5-dev
sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-doc
```

The docs for these are here:

```
/usr/share/doc/qtmultimedia5-doc
/usr/share/doc/qtmultimedia5-doc-html
/usr/include/qt5/QtMultimedia/
```

and examples:

```
sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-examples
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/multimedia
```